# problem locating the xml within the xml search of the code

Tags: coldfusion, lucee

I have defined the xml as below with all information in it.

```
<application>
    <name>CRUD Generator</name>
    <author>User 1</author>
    <version>Beta</version>
    <description>Generate ColdFusion Components based on Database Tables</description>
    <menucontributions >
        <contribution target="rdsview" >
            <menu name="CFC Generator">
                <action name="Create CFC" handlerid="startCRUD" showResponse="no">
                    <input name="location" default="paths" label="Enter destination" tooltip="Location where generated CFCs will be stored" type="projectdir" required="true"/>
                    <input name="generateService" label="Generate Service?" tooltip="Generate service to be consumed" type="boolean" checked="true"/>
                    <input name="scriptbased" label= "Script CFC?" type="boolean" />
                </action>
            </menu>
        </contribution>
    </menucontributions>
    <!-- Define Handlers-->
    <handlers>
        <handler id="startCRUD" type="CFM" filename="cfcGen.cfm" />
    </handlers>
    <rdsview>
        <database name="dbo.AcademicDbo">
            <table name="abc">
                <fields>
                    <field name="id" type="int" length="" nullallowed="NO" primarykey="id"/>
                    <field name="CoreCode" type="varchar" length="50" nullallowed="NO" primarykey="id"/>
                    <field name="CoreDescription" type="varchar" length="250" nullallowed="NO" primarykey="id"/>
                    <field name="SubCriteriaID" type="int" length="" nullallowed="NO" primarykey="id"/>
                    <field name="modifiedby" type="int" length="" nullallowed="YES" primarykey="id"/>
                    <field name="insertby" type="int" length="" nullallowed="YES" primarykey="id"/>
                    <field name="modifieddate" type="datetime" length="" nullallowed="NO" primarykey="id"/>
                    <field name="insertdate" type="datetime" length="" nullallowed="NO" primarykey="id"/>
                    <field name="iLastActionBy" type="int" length="" nullallowed="YES" primarykey="id"/>
                    <field name="dLastActionDate" type="datetime" length="" nullallowed="YES" primarykey="id"/>
                    <field name="iLastActionBranch" type="int" length="" nullallowed="YES" primarykey="id"/>
                    
                </fields>
            </table>
        </database>
    </rdsview>
</application>
```

now i have the cfc but i am having some trouble finding the xml and create a working code so my components can find its value but it is not working, i am definately missing some pieces here, my xml knowlledge is not good so having hard time doing it, i already tried 3  hours but none came out, now i seek guidance

```
<cffunction name="parseIDEEventInfo" returntype="struct" access="public">
    <cfargument name="xml" type="string" required="true" />
    <cfset extxml= xmlParse(ARGUMENTS.xml)>
    
    <cfset extsys = {}>
    <cfset dsarr=ArrayNew(1)>
    <cfset extxmlinput = xmlSearch(extxml, "/event/user/input")>
    <cfset extxmltable ="">
    <!--<cfset extsys.input = {}>-->
    <cfloop index="i" from="1" to="#arrayLen(extxmlinput)#" >
        <cfset StructInsert(extsys.input,"#extxmlinput[i].xmlAttributes.name#","#extxmlinput[i].xmlAttributes.value#")>
    </cfloop>
    
    <cfdump var="#extxml#">
    <cfset dsarr=xmlSearch(extxml, "/rdsview/database")>
    <cfdump var="#dsarr#">
    <cfset extsys.input.datasource = dsarr[1].XMLAttributes.name>
    <cfdump var="#extxml#">
    <!---<cfset extsys.input.database = getDBType(extsys.input.datasource)>--->
    <cfset extsys.table = []>
    <cfset extxmltable = xmlSearch(extxml, "/database/table")>
    
    <cfloop index="i" from="1" to="#arrayLen(extxmltable)#">
        <cfif(find('.',extxmltable[i].xmlAttributes.name))>
            <cfset extxmltable[i].xmlAttributes.name = getToken(extxmltable[i].xmlAttributes.name, 2, '.')>
        </cfif>
        <cfset table = StructNew()>
        <cfset table.name=extxmltable[i].xmlAttributes.name>
        <cfset table.table=extxmltable[i].xmlAttributes.name>
        <cfset table.file=tCase(extxmltable[i].xmlAttributes.name)>
        <cfset table.field=[]>
        <cfif( StructkeyExists(extsys.input,"fromfb"))>
            <cfset table.field = getColumns(extxmltable[i].fields.field,"true")>
        <cfelse>
            <cfset table.field = getColumns(extxmltable[i].fields.field,"false")>
        </cfif>
        <cfset table.key = []>
        <cfset table.foreign = []>
        <cfloop index="j" from="1" to="#arrayLen(table.field)#">
            <cfif(table.field[j].isPrimaryKey)>
                <cfset arrayAppend(table.key, table.field[j])>
            </cfif>
            <cfif table.field[j].isForeignKey >
            <cfset arrayAppend(table.foreign, table.field[j])>
            </cfif>
    
        </cfloop>
        
        <cfset arrayAppend(extsys.table, table)>
    </cfloop>
        
    <!---- return success ---->
    <cfreturn extsys />     
</cffunction>
```

the function which i am modifying to do it and make it working order

Comment: What is not working? Are you getting errors? What exactly are you trying to get?

Comment: there are many errors but the main part where i am not understanding the part is how and why it does not search the database and the table because that is the portion where it is building its core logic

Comment: Would be informative and helpful if you mention what errors exactly you're getting.

Comment: this is the error https://pastebin.com/a6TMvNyv

Comment: Has @haxtbh indicated, pls include in your question the error that you are getting when you run the code. Burying it in a paste bin in a comment ain't the way to approach this. What dumps out on line 53? What does "The element at position 1 cannot be found." tell you? Also when you have a problem with a concept like "searching XML", don't give us dozens of lines of irrelevant code. Just give us enough to demonstrate the problem, and if you make it portable and runnable (eg: https://trycf.com/gist/27d01ecf27b4fde5a5ef38e821fd4077/lucee5?theme=monokai), so much the better.

Comment: This is not a ColdFusion or Lucee question. It's an xpath question... your xpath does not reflect the structure of your XML. What you really need to do is to do some xpath tutorials to learn how it works, rather than just guessing.

Answer (score 0):

You are searching for `/rdsview/database` in your XML document, but the top level of the doc is `applicaction`.

There are two relevant strategies here. First: just get yer search string correct, it would be: `/applicaction/rdsview/database`. This returns results from your `xmlSearch`.

Secondly if you just wanted the nodes matching a subhierarchy of `/rdsview/database` anywhere in the doc (not necessarily immediately within `application`) you could search for `//rdsview/database`.

However in this case it's the former you want to be doing, given `/rdsview/database` only appears in one place in the hierarchy in the first place.

I have found [http://zvon.org/comp/r/tut-XPath_1.html#Pages~List_of_XPaths](http://zvon.org/comp/r/tut-XPath_1.html#Pages%7EList_of_XPaths) to be a good reference for explaining how XPath strings work.